# Корзина покупок на jQuery

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Вопрос таков, нужно сделать корзину покупок на PHP+Ajax. Есть код на html, он генерируется на php.
Все никак не могу понять, как в javascript различать между собой все эти товары.

```
<div class="offer_header">Название</div> <div class="offer_composition"> <div class="offer_composition_text">Описание</div> <div class="offer_composition_detail"><a>Подробно</a></div> </div> <div class="offer_tools"> <div class="offer_price"> <div class="offer_price_int">100 руб.</div> </div> <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="15"/> <div class="offer_add"><a>В корзину</a></div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть [способ реализации корзины](http://makecode.ru/2011/01/basket-jquery/) на jQuery с использованием cookie. Все достаточно просто, если знаете основы JS/jQuery. Основной принцип - сохранение в куках id и кол-ва выбранных товаров. Естественно, что при оформлении заказа, не возникнет проблем вытащить всю инфу товара по этим id.

Comment: или хранить все заказы на сервере по сессии.